# Text between two lines

Tags: boxes

i'd like to write words that fit between two lines.

i found the following code:

```
\documentclass[parskip,paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{mb}
{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}\begin{minipage}[4mm]{\columnwidth-2\fboxsep}}%
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\par\vspace{10mm}\noindent\fbox{\usebox{\mybox}}\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{mb}
\Huge Stackexchange
\end{mb}
\end{document}
```

what i like to get is something like this:

[image]

edit:
to be more clear ... sorry!

i'd like the lines to be the full width of the page with only some characters in front of the two lines.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example puts the text in a box, then it reduces the height and depth to put a frame (`\fbox`) without margin around the shrinked box. The original height and depth is kept by `\vphantom`.

```
\documentclass[parskip,paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\newcommand*{\TwoLinesBox}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{\,#1\,}%
    \vphantom{\copy0}% keep original height and depth
    \sbox2{x}% new height
    \ht0=\ht2 %
    \dp0=0pt %
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% \fbox without additional inner margins
    \fbox{\copy0}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\noindent
\TwoLinesBox{Stackexchange}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Half open box, spanning the line

The following example uses a `tabular` environment with one column that spans the whole line width. The two lines are set at the beginning of the row.

The code uses plain TeX macros and primitives. Literature:

- Donald E. Knuth: *The TeXbook*
- [Victor Eijkhout: *TeX by Topic*](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf)

The example file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment{twolines}{%
  \par
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\AddTwoLines}p{\linewidth}@{}}%
}{%
  \end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand*{\AddTwoLines}{%
  \noindent
  \sbox0{\vrule\vphantom{x}}%
  \rlap{%
    \vbox{\hrule width\linewidth}%
  }%
  \rlap{%
    \raise\ht0\vbox{\hrule width\linewidth}%
  }%
  \copy0 %
  \,\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{twolines}
  Stack\\
  Exchange
\end{twolines}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: thanx! that is nearly that what i want to get! but how can i make the lines to be full width of the page? do you have a reference for sbox0, sbox2, ht0, ht2 ... i haven't found anything how to use this to modify your example.

Comment: ok ... once again my fault :( but how can i add a vertical "|" at the end? i left it in my example to visualize that the end of the two lines is not the end ...